# AngularJS - Filter on ng-repeat, hiding the column heading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a massive JSON response from a REST service that contains lots of cities over the world... the structure is like this (here's just a sample... it would normally consist of 100-200 places and comes from a service - I have just set it to the $scope item for better understanding):

```
$scope.cityData = [
            {
                "country": "Deutschland",
                "cities": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Berlin",
                        "country": "Deutschland",
                        "browserUrl": "berlin",
                        "clusterId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Hamburg",
                        "country": "Deutschland",
                        "browserUrl": "hamburg",
                        "clusterId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "München",
                        "country": "Deutschland",
                        "browserUrl": "muenchen",
                        "clusterId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "Köln",
                        "country": "Deutschland",
                        "browserUrl": "koeln",
                        "clusterId": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "country": "Schweiz",
                "cities": [
                    {
                        "id": 15,
                        "name": "Zürich",
                        "country": "Schweiz",
                        "browserUrl": "zuerich",
                        "clusterId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 16,
                        "name": "Geneva",
                        "country": "Schweiz",
                        "browserUrl": "geneva",
                        "clusterId": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "country": "Österreich",
                "cities": [
                    {
                        "id": 19,
                        "name": "Vienna",
                        "country": "Österreich",
                        "browserUrl": "vienna",
                        "clusterId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 20,
                        "name": "Graz",
                        "country": "Österreich",
                        "browserUrl": "graz",
                        "clusterId": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 20,
                        "name": "Linz",
                        "country": "Österreich",
                        "browserUrl": "linz",
                        "clusterId": null
                    }

                ]
            }
        ];
```

Now on my interface I wish to group these like so:

```
- Country
  ---- City
  ---- City
  ---- City
- Country
  ---- City
  ---- City
  ---- City
```

I also wish to filter the repeat using an input field, so I have the following input and `ng-repeat`s on my interface:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="cityFilter">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="c in cityData | filter: c.country">
      {{ c.country }}

       <div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="d in c.cities | filter: cityFilter">
        {{ d.name }}
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

this works great however the c.country title is always shown regardless of the filter... how should I change my HTML / directives so that the `c.country` disappears when the `cityFilter` filter contains a city name that is not applicable / found in that country?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose country in a span and Use ng-show.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="cityFilter">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="c in cityData | filter: c.country">
        <span ng-show="(c.cities | filter: cityFilter).length > 0">{{ c.country }}</span>

       <div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="d in c.cities | filter: cityFilter">
          {{ d.name }}
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```